# What to do when reinstalling Ubuntu when /home on a separate HDD?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

One of the reasons I believe that having /home on a separate hard drive was that it would be easier to maintain you're data if you need to do a re-install.

My question though is it as simple as just running a new install on the OS hard drive or do you need to do certain steps (apart from a back-up) before re-installing Ubuntu?

For example do you need to use same username/computername and passwords?

In my case Ubuntu 14.04 is the only OS used and I have encrypted the OS but not /home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What to do when reinstalling Ubuntu when /home on a seperate HDD?

Mount /home but do **not** set it to format the partition. Use the same username during re-installation.

> For example do you need to use same username

No, but it would be adviced. If you use another name you will end up with TWO users in /home each with their own permissions and (same) user ID. You will need to do a lot of manual work to have both work together. It is possible also to just remove the old user but what would be the idea behind putting it on a separate partition if you do that?

> computername

No.

> and passwords?

No.